# why does my app miss an activity?

Tags: android, view, android-activity

Hi i recently asked a question regarding my app and the good people here found out it would force close as my images werent properly handled with bitmap factory, but given as im an amateur i decided to take out the images to make sure my code was good.... and its not

what i wanted is main to open secondactivity which lists 4 buttons the top one taking you too bathactivity

what i have is main skips secondactivity and takes you too bathactivity and if you press up it will take you too secondactivity but the button here does nothing

but i have no errors in my code, and the app never force closes, so do i just post code or logcat too?

any help appreciated

main.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;


public class main extends Activity {
Button ok;
EditText name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String nameStr = name.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondactivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("NAMEDATA",nameStr);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

secondactivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class secondactivity extends Activity {
TextView t;
Button button;
Button button2;
Button button3;
Button button4;






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    String n = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("NAMEDATA");
    t.setText(n);

    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    setButtonOnClickListener();

}


private void setButtonOnClickListener(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(secondactivity.this, bathactivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.second, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

bathactivity.java

```
package com.example.myapplication;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.Button;

public class bathactivity extends Activity {
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bath);
    button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextbutton);




     }



}
```

Comment: "...the good people here found out it would force close..." you should thank the good people here for their time by clicking the check mark next to the answer which helped the most to accept it as correct. As far as the question, post the code which isn't working.

Comment: Thank you sooo much another guy asked me too and couldn't find it will do so now and add code

Comment: @codemagic okay done and done

Comment: Thank you and see my answer I have put comments in the code that will hopefully explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ofcourse it will directly take you to `bathactivity`. You asked it. Inside the `onCreate` of `secondactivity` you are calling this `setButtonOnClickListener();` function, which creates an `Intent` and starts the `bathactivity`. Do not call the function inside the `onCreate`. Just use it directly in the XML file, where in `android:onClick` you can just define the function name for the button.

Comment: No prob. Your welcome. Please do comment if still you are having any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `secondactivity` isn't getting skipped at all. It is getting called which starts your `onCreate()` per the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html). Inside `onCreate()` you call `setButtonOnClickListener()` which has an `Intent` that takes you to `bathactivity`. So, while `secondactivity` does get called, you don't see it because you immediately go to the next `Activity`.

Change this code in `secondactivity`

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

setButtonOnClickListener();

}
private void setButtonOnClickListener(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(secondactivity.this, bathactivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

to something like

```
button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
button4 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() /* this is one of several ways to set the 
                                                 * OnClickListener which you are not doing
                                                */
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(secondactivity.this, bathactivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);   // this will start your Activity when clicking the Button
    }
});
```

and it should give you what you want.